# Finding the Largest increase in an array filled with random numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

For instance you are given an array [3,5,8,10,6,12,4]. You are to find the largest possible increase between two pairs of element i and j where j > i.

In the above case the answer would return 9 -> 12 - 3 = 9.

So i though of the obvious solution which is O(N^2).
Here is my code

```
public class Max {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = {3,5,8,10,6,12,4};

        System.out.println(getMax(array));


    }


    public static int getMax(int [] arr)
    {
        int maxVal = 0;

        for(int i = arr.length-1; i>0; i--)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<i; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i]-arr[j] > maxVal)
                {

                    maxVal = arr[i] - arr[j];
                }
            }

        }

        return maxVal;
    }

}
```

However i was wondering if it is possible to improve the solution to O(NlogN) because what if we use divide and conquer approach? Can someone guide me ?

**UPDATE
I simply can't find the max and min because the index of j has to be greater than index i. If i simply just look for the max and min value then i might get a case where index i is greater than index j and that is not allowed.**

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-difference-between-two-elements/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the minimum so far and update accordingly:

```
min = array[0]
max_diff = 0
for each element e, starting from the second:
  if e - min > max_diff:
    max_diff = e - min
  if e < min:
    min = e
```

Comment: check my update please i apologize i forgot to mention a crucial point.

Comment: This is O(1) extra space and O(n) time so sounds like a winner to me. Per http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-difference-between-two-elements/ this seems like the best option.